# The shell game. How do I make objects move, specially in certain curve but with random order?

Tags: java, processing

I'm making the game known as the shell game.

I have been stuck for a while, when it comes to make my cups switch places in a random order but with a certain curve motion. Should I somehow use the belzier curve?

How and where in my code can I hide the ball?

Your help is really appreciated :-)

```java
cup cupLeft;       
cup cupMiddle;   
cup cupRight;  
coin coinGold;   

void setup() {   
    size(1250,750);    
    background(255);   

    int x = width/2;   
    int y = height/2;    
    cupLeft = new cup(x,y);    

    int x2 = 1050;    
    int y2 = 300;    
    cupMiddle = new cup(x2,y2);    

    int x3 = 1500;    
    int y3 = 375;    
    cupRight = new cup(x3,y3);    

    int x5 = width/2;    
    int y5 = height/2;    
    coinGold = new coin(x5,y5);    
}    

void draw() {    
    display_bW();      
    cupLeft.display();    
    cupMiddle.display();    
    cupRight.display();    

    coinGold.display();    
}
```

The code for `display_bW()`;

```java
PImage bW;        
bW = loadImage("brickWall.jpg");    
bW.resize(1250,750);    
imageMode(CENTER);    
image( bW, width/2, height/2);    
bW.resize(800,800);    
//The TITLE    
fill(255,215,0);    
textAlign(CENTER);    
textSize(100);    
text("The shell game", width/2, 150);    
// Instruction    
fill(255,215,0);     
textAlign(CENTER);    
textSize(55);    
text("Find the coin. Press space to start the game", width/2, 700);
```

The Class for cup:

```java
class cup {    
    int x;    
    int y;    
    int dir;    

    cup(int x1, int y1) {     
        x=x1;    
        y=y1;    
        dir = 1;    
    }    

    void move(int speed) {     
        //My thought was to write something in here that could determine the speed and direction of the cups.    

    }    

    void display() {   

        fill(255,0,0);    
        quad(x-550,y+100,x-330,y+100,x-380,y-100,x-500,y-100);     
        ellipse(x-440,y-100,120,50);     
        ellipse(x-440,y+100, 220, 50);    
     }    
}
```

If you have any other suggetions to do something in a better way or more efficient way, let me know.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post [mcve]

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions : packages, attributes, variables, parameters, method have to start in **lowerCase**, while class, interface should start in **UpperCase**

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. The best advice we can give you is to [break your problem down into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take those steps on one at a time.

For example, can you create a simple program that shows two rectangles switching places? You can research [animation](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation). Start with something simple, without curves at first. The `lerp()` function might come in handy here. Get that working before you try to implement the curves.

For the curving, the `curvePoint()` or `bezierPoint()` functions might come in handy. All of these functions can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

Build your program so that you can hardcode two indexes and show the animation of them switching places.

Finally, build on what you have so far to randomly generate the indexes.

If you get stuck on one of these steps, you can create a new post with a more specific question along with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!